# Daubechies Wavelet and Matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I want to use [`waverec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/waverec.html) to evaluate a linear combination of the scaled and shifted wavelet  of the form

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{2^n-1}d_{nj} 2^{-n}\psi_{ij} (\frac{t-j}{2^n}) +c_{00}\phi(t)  $$
at $t=k2^{-n} $ for $k=0\dots2^{n}-1$. I know how do it for the Haar wavelet, namely

```
[c,l]=wavedec(zeros(1,8),3,'haar')
waverec(2^(3/2)*[c00 d10 d20 d21 d30 d31 d32 d33],l,'haar')
```

But how can you do the same thing for Daubechies wavelets? The problem being that the array `c` does not have 8 entries but 28:

```
[c,l]=wavedec(zeros(1,8),3,'db4')

c =

  Columns 1 through 14

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


  Columns 15 through 28

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


l =

     7     7     7     7     8
```

The Question is related to [Number of Daubechies coefficients](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/number-of-daubechies-coefficients), but I do not understand the answer.

Comment: Where is the $i$ in the equation after the sigmas?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the post. In the index of the basis function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `wavdec` function does not produce a DWT which is non-redundant. Instead, `wavdec` takes you *N* levels down the decomposition process. In other words, you shouldn't expect to get 8 coefficients back.